# VSCode Prettier

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Не могу оставлять пустые фигурные скобки т.е не могу их переносить в другую строчку Prettier автоматом убирает пустые символы и получается `css(styles={}){}`. а хотелось бы чтоб `было css(styles={      }){}`

на пример[image: скрин]

```
css(styles = {}) {
    Object.keys(styles).forEach(key => (this.$el.style[key] = styles[key]))
}
```

это то что у меня

[image: Скрин]

```
  css(styles = {
    тут должен быть пробел и перенос в другую строку
  }) {
    Object.keys(styles).forEach(key => (this.$el.style[key] = styles[key]))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, такое поведение нельзя переопределить. Подробнее о том, какие свойства дает определять prettier: https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html

Comment: я читал уже в prettier.io и вроде ничего не нашел или не понял)